# Return new form of arrays using lodash methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

My first array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Gilman",
    "entryCheckPointId": 1,
    "entryCheckPoint": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Checkpoint A"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Arshad",
    "entryCheckPointId": 3,
    "entryCheckPoint": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Checkpoint C"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Illyas",
    "entryCheckPointId": 3,
    "entryCheckPoint": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Checkpoint C"
    }
  }
]
```

Second Array:

```
[ 
  { 
    "entryCheckPointId": 1, 
    "count": 1
  },
  { 
    "entryCheckPointId": 3, 
    "count": 2 
  } 
]
```

I want to match these both using entryCheckPointId and i want to return a new form of array like this

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    label: 'Checkpoint A', 
    value: 1, // count 
    color: 'green'
  }, 
  {
    label: 'Checkpoint C', 
    value: 2, // count
    color: 'pink'
  }, 
]
```

I tried with map function, but it is not working correctly as i expected.

I tried this code:

```
var mergedList = _.map(a1, function(item){
    return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(a2, { id: item.id }));
}); // a1 is firstArray and a2 is secondArray
```

Is this possible to do using any of the lodash library?

And one doubt, is lodash and underscore both are same?

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: Sure, i will make fiddle :) wait

Comment: @MohamedSameer make a fiddle if you want, but post the code **here** also.

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: I dont know how to do it in lodash but in plain js it is just mapping and filtering the first array with the second one

Comment: can you post some piece of code? i need output its ok even if it works in native js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript (which I guess is not what you are looking for but it may be helpful):

```js
var x = [{"id": 1,"name": "Gilman","entryCheckPointId": 1,"entryCheckPoint": {"id": 1,"name": "Checkpoint A"}},{"id": 2,"name": "Arshad","entryCheckPointId": 3,"entryCheckPoint": {"id": 3,"name": "Checkpoint C"}},{"id": 3,"name": "Illyas","entryCheckPointId": 3,"entryCheckPoint": {"id": 3,"name": "Checkpoint C"}}]

var y = [ { "entryCheckPointId": 1, "count": 1},{ "entryCheckPointId": 3, "count": 2 }]

var colors  = ["pink", "red", "green"]

var result = y.map((a,i)=>({
  label: x.filter(b=>b.entryCheckPointId == a.entryCheckPointId)[a.count-1].entryCheckPoint.name,
  value: a.count, 
  color: colors[i]
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i want two colors to be different.

Comment: Where you get the colors from?

Comment: Just i want to put static two different colors.

Comment: In that case you could have a colors array and get the color from there. I'll show you now

Comment: Ok sure, i am waiting

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Please find two examples of how this looks with `lodash` and without. Both examples utilize some of the new ES6 features (like shorthand object literals , object destructuring etc).

```js
var data1 = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Gilman", "entryCheckPointId": 1, "entryCheckPoint": { "id": 1, "name": "Checkpoint A" }}, { "id": 2, "name": "Arshad", "entryCheckPointId": 3, "entryCheckPoint": { "id": 3, "name": "Checkpoint C" }}, { "id": 3, "name": "Illyas", "entryCheckPointId": 3, "entryCheckPoint": { "id": 3, "name": "Checkpoint C" }}]
var data2 = [ { "entryCheckPointId": 1, "count": 1 }, { "entryCheckPointId": 3,  "count": 2 } ]
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

var lodashResult = _.map(data2, ({entryCheckPointId, count}, i) => ({
  label: _.find(data1, {entryCheckPointId}).entryCheckPoint.name,
  count,
  color: colors[i]
}))

var noLodashResult = data2.map(({entryCheckPointId, count}, i) => ({
  label: data1.find(x => x.entryCheckPointId == entryCheckPointId).entryCheckPoint.name,
  count,
  color: colors[i]
}))

console.log('lodash', lodashResult)
console.log('noLodash', noLodashResult)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see the `_.lodash` is somewhat simpler and shorter.